# Object with transparency makes the object behind it transparent

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency

I have an object that consists of two layers, one of which is transparent, the other is opaque. However when viewing the opaque object through the transparent one the opaque material has some transparency and you can see objects that are behind it. Can anyone let me know why this is happening?

The screenshot below shows the issue along with the node structure of the transparent layer.

[image]

Comment: Can you please add another screenshot so that we can see the hidden objects please?

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to connect surface shaders to the volume socket of the material.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos You aren't, but I don't think that it would cause the problem.

Comment: Can you post a [.blend](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)?

Comment: @pycoder Yeah, just pointing that out as a possible source of problems. There is probably something similar wrong with the other material, just impossible to know with the available info